# mapping multiple column to one property in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

[EDIT] basically i want to map one property to different columns based on query. In this case for query 1 to column c1, for query 2 to c2 column. And also ap this class mapper to different tables based on query. Like for query 1 and 2 to table t1 and for query 3 to table t2.

I have five queries which return same list of Strings.

```
select (c1) from t1;

select (c2) from t1; 

select (c3) from t2;
```

So can i write one Model class which i can reuse to map result set of all queries.

```
class mapper{
      private String data;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Model class models the db tables (not really but lets keep it simply) not queries or their results.  Write what are your data/tables, what are you trying to achieve. As it is now, I can't even tell what are you asking about.

Comment: You don't give us much to work on... Usually I tend to first find out whether  things really are re-usable, and then refactor,

Comment: hi, thanks for quick response, i am sorry if i am not clear enough. i have updated the question. please see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your entity class maps a table object in database not a query. So instead of 5 sql queries you have, you have to define a table view in your DB that reflects those queries. Than you can map the columns of that view to your Java class.

Comment: thanks, but problem is all these three query are for independent api.